# SharePoint Modern News: How to detect if news has been published more than once?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

When a modern SharePoint news is being published we send a notification to a certain audience via Power Automate Flow. Easy via a trigger on the Site Pages library:

[image]

We detect via the `PromotedState=2` property that the news has been published (vs. just being edited) and send the notification.

Now the notification message shall look *different* when the page is being *edited and re-published*. This seems to be trickier than I initially thought.

I thought about using the `FirstPublishedDate` and `Modified` properties somehow but apparently the `Modified` date can change without the need to re-publish the page.

So the question is: given a SharePoint modern news page, how can I detect that this page has been published more than once - without going back into the item history or tracking changes of the `PromotedState` property myself? Some kind of `LastPublishedDate` would really be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It hit me that the **major version** of the news post could serve as publish count. Every time you publish the news a new major version is created as well. Drafts are stored as minor versions.

BUT there is one quirk with modern news: when you publish a news post from the page's three-dot-menu instead of the edit view the `PromotedState` is not set to `2`!

[image]

So you end up with a "published" page (in the classic SharePoint sense, with a major version) but not with a "published" news post (in the "modern news" sense). I could cuss for days on end.

So I ended up going back into the version history, counting all major versions that have `PromotedState` set to `2`. This gives me the publish count while ignoring any initial games the author played with the "native" publish function of SharePoint.

Bonus quirk: you can "promote" a "SharePoint-published" page to a real published news post:

[image]

But this does not update `PromotedState` immediately. You rather have to put the page into edit mode and publish it again. Only then is the `PromotedState` set to `2`.

Comment: You can accept this answer and upvote it to help other users with the same problem find effective content more directly. :)

Comment: @ElsieLu_MSFT Yep I will do as soon as StackExchange lets me do this :) One has to wait 2 or 3 days for other answers to come in I guess.